# Refresh tokens not being generated for identity server 4 on Azure. Only getting Authorization codes

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have deployed an ASP.Net core app on Azure that has an API, Web App and Identity Server 4. I have an [Authorize] attribute on Web app HomeController endpoint so that it redirects to Identity Server Login page. But on logging in I get the error "An error occurred while processing your request."

The same implementation redirects properly on localhost IIS and IIS Express without errors. I have loaded a Self-signed certificate to Azure. Also set HttpsOnly = OFF in Azure. When I inspect Cookies during redirection, the identity server Cookie (idsrv.session) loads briefly before disappearing.

Code from Web Project StartUp.cs

```
            services.AddMvc();


            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {   
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";

            })
                 .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                 {
                     options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                     options.ClientId = "mvc";
                     options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                     options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                     options.Scope.Add("MFSAPI.OPERATOR");
                     options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                     options.SaveTokens = true;
                     options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                 })
                 .AddCookie("Cookies");
```

Code from Identity Server project StartUp.cs

```
 services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
            {
                iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
                iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                  .AddSigningCredential(cert)
                  .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection"),
                            sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
                  .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection"),
                            sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
                  .AddAspNetIdentity<Users>()
                .AddProfileService<ProfileServices>();
```

Some Identity Server logs

```
[INF] Executed action method "Nmicros.Identity.Server.Quickstart.Account.AccountController.Login (Nmicros.Identity.Server)", returned result "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectResult" in 902.3143ms. (50a9e262)
[INF] Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to "/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=
[INF] Executed action "Nmicros.Identity.Server.Quickstart.Account.AccountController.Login 
[INF] Request finished in 1076.9641ms 302  (791a596a)
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET 
[INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: "IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint" for "/connect/authorize/callback" (f7642de5)
[INF] Authorize endpoint response
AuthorizeResponseLog { SubjectId: "1", ClientId: "mvc", RedirectUri: "", State: , Scope: "openid profile MFSAPI.OPERATOR offline_access", Error: null, ErrorDescription: null } (22d160a8)
[INF] AuthenticationScheme: "Identity.Application" signed in. (c66dd7e7)
```

I expect to have identity server properly redirecting to the Web client and providing a refresh token. Instead when I check the persisted grants table I have only authorization_code instead of refresh_token Types.

Comment: Did you configure the proper URLs for the clients? RedirectUrls, grant types in your azure environment? The logs you posted have `&redirect_uri=` empty. Shouldn't you have the redirect url from your MVC client there? The refresh token is never created because the redirect check fails, most likely.

Comment: @jpgrassi I didn't include the full redirect urls in the logs I posted here coz they were too long and also for safety reasons, but yes, I configured them. Also, just tried the same Identity server implementation with the default mvc web app and it is working well with it on azure. So problem is my web app most likely.

Comment: Ah I see. Then I'd suggest you compare them to see what's different as it's hard for us to help. Check the NuGet packages as well.

Comment: @SolomonMetta, "An error occurred while processing your request." is web server's default error, so you have to switch logging levels for Microsoft, System etc to get the reason. you can additionally switch the default level to "Debug" to get more info from IdSrv.